# git push succeeded, but remote repository is not updated or synchronized

Tags: git, push, synchronized, repo

I'm learning git on my mac os x. I've enabled ssh on my mac, and try to simulate both remote repo and local repo.

I run into the case that after I change my file in local repo, git add/commit/push succeeded, I don't see the change on my remote repo. My steps are like this:
Create the remote repo

```
$cd ~/learn
$mkdir gittest
$cd gittest/
$git init
$git config --global user.name "username"
$git config --global user.email "useremail"
$touch readme
$git add readme
$git commit -m "empty"
```

OK, everything fine, then in another directory, I did:

```
$cd ~/learn/client
$git clone trosky@localhost:/Users/trosky/learn/gittest
$cd gittest
$vi readme(add one line)
$git add .
$git commit -m "add line"
$git push origin master:refs/for/master
```

Seems ok, git push prints:

```
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 274 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To x@localhost:/Users/trosky/learn/gittest
 * [new branch]      master -> refs/for/master

$git log
```

I can see 2 records.

```
commit e4a3af902d8d3b708509073e4fd2281ab8355cf0
Author: username <useremail>
Date:   Fri Dec 23 20:54:52 2016 +0800

    add line

commit e024e83b1227f8d1e585cad66e7a4f9b3bb12462
Author: username <useremail>
Date:   Fri Dec 23 20:53:18 2016 +0800

    empty
```

But in the gittest directory, I can only see 1 git log and the file is still empty

```
$git log
commit e024e83b1227f8d1e585cad66e7a4f9b3bb12462
Author: username <useremail>
Date:   Fri Dec 23 20:53:18 2016 +0800

    empty
```

This is so weird. I repeated the process several times, each time the same result. Why is that and how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re pushing to `refs/for/master`, not `refs/heads/master` so what you pushed will not appear as a “real” branch. Instead, you’re pushing to `refs/for/*` which is a common refspec from code reviewing tools like [Gerrit](https://www.gerritcodereview.com/).

If you’re using one of these tools, you should check whether your push generated a code review item somewhere; or consult the manual to make sure that you’re doing everything correctly.

Otherwise, if you just want to push the master branch, then push correctly to `refs/heads/master` or just use `git push origin master` assuming the default configuration for your remote.

Answer (score -2):

After PUSH you have to merge both the repo to move that changes in remote repo.

Comment: and how to do that?